# Single query for all records having no key in a join table and those having a matching key

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, mysql, searchlogic

I have a trip that has many residencies.  I need a single query that returns all trips where no residency information has been specified.  And all trips that match a specified residency.

I can get the first from this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `trips` WHERE (((NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM residencies WHERE trips.id = residencies.trip_id))
```

But to get the second, I need to add this bit as well:

```
INNER JOIN `residencies` ON (`trips`.`id` = `residencies`.`trip_id`)
```

Adding the join before the WHERE clause is asking for results that have a residency ID and no residency IDs. That obviously returns nothing.  So how can I write this to get the full result set in one query? Stored procedures aren't allowed on this.

I'm using Rails, so it's a bonus (but definitely not required) if the answer is Rails-specific.  And a huge bonus if someone can show how this can be done with the searchlogic plugin.

Currently, I have the first requirement as a named scope:

```
Trip.named_scope :residencies_empty, :conditions => ['NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM residencies WHERE trips.id = residencies.trip_id)']
```

The second requirement is available through searchlogic:

```
Trip.residences_id_equals(id)
```

The ideal solution would be a searchlogic scope that looks like this:

```
Trip.residencies_null_or_residencies_id_equals(id)
```

Comment: Could you post the definition of the trips and residencies tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using another "EXIST" for the trips with the specific residency:

```
SELECT * FROM `trips` WHERE 
  (NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM residencies WHERE trips.id = residencies.trip_id))
  OR
  (EXISTS (SELECT id FROM residencies WHERE trips.id = residencies.trip_id 
           AND other_criteria_for_specific_residency)
  )
```

This seems to be the most readable solution, but if performance is important, you should check EXPAIN to see how this is optimized (as with most complex queries in MySql).

Comment: Thank you, Tomas! I banged my head on this for several hours!

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
SELECT * FROM `trips`
    LEFT JOIN  residencies ON trips.id = residencies.trip_id
```

You will get data in all of the columns from `trips`, but data will only be populated in columns from residencies where a row existed, if no residencies row existed those columns will be null.

Comment: from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for table A and B always contains all records of the "left" table (A), even if the join-condition does not find any matching record in the "right" table (B). This means that if the ON clause matches 0 (zero) records in B, the join will still return a row in the result—but with NULL in each column from B.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to combine the results of the two queries?